# Implementing custom client validation based off of another textbox input

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

I've been dabbling a little into MVC 5's custom client validation (MVC's GetClientValidationRules and jQuery's validator). I've been able to successfully implement a validator to check whether the user selects a date that is in the past. But what about if I need to check if a user's textbox input is greater than another textbox's input of theirs?

I have it working fine without unobtrusive validation/server-side, but not **with** unobtrusive validation.

Here's an example.

**Model**

```
public Nullable<int> ItemsPurchased
public Nullable<int> ItemsReturned
```

A custom DataAnnotation has been made for ItemsReturned to check whether its value <= ItemsPurchased. Implementing GetClientValidationRules to actually get ItemsPurchased's current value is where I'm having trouble in the code.

Comment: You could consider using the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) library which contains many validation attributes such as `[GreaterThan]` or to write your own conditional validation attributes, [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1) is a good resource for explaining how to implement `IClientValidatable` and write the associated scripts necessary for client side validation

Comment: I would prefer to steer away from doing NuGets/downloading packages for a few reasons, one being that the machine I work on doesn't actually have internet access. Thanks though, I'll check out the article in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a variable in my custom data annotation. I'm not sure why this didn't come to me naturally...but here's my solution.

**DataAnnotation (Applied to ItemsReturned)**

```
public string purchasedQuantityField { get; set; }
public ReturnedAttribute(string quantity) {
    purchasedQuantityField = quantity;
}
...
(in GetClientValidationRules)
ModelClientvalidationRule purchaseRule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
purchaseRule.ValidationType = "purchaserestriction";
purchaseRule.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString;
purchaseRule.ValidationParameters["otherfield"] = purchasedQuantityField;
```

Usage in the model:

```
[Returned("ItemsPurchased", ErrorMessage = "Returned Items cannot be greater than the number of Items Purchased.")]
```

Then I made my own JS file with the custom client validation rules, **CustomClientValidation.js**:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("purchaserestriction", function (value, element, params) {
    var purchasedFieldVal = $('input[name="' + params.otherfield + '"]').val();
    if (purchasedFieldVal && value) {
        var returnedVal = parseInt(value);
        var purchasedVal = parseInt(purchasedFieldVal);
        if (returnedVal <= purchasedVal) return true;
        else return false;
    }
);
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("purchaserestriction", ["otherfield"], function (options) {
    options.rules["purchaserestriction"] = options.params;
    if (options.message) options.messages["purchaserestriction"] = options.message;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with jQuery Validation. You can create custom rules which will check whatever you want. Take a look at this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('name_of_the_rule', function (value, element, param) {
    //put there your validation

    return isValid; // return bool here if valid or not.
}, 'Put here your error message!');


$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        field1: {
            yourRuleName: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my specific question though. How do I validate that one textbox <= another textbox?

Comment: Replace comment "//put there your validation" with the code which will get value from one textbox and from second one and compare them ($(textbox1).val() <= $(textbox2).val()). Quite simple...

Comment: Oh...duh, sorry. Saw this literally as soon as I woke up. What about implementing and adding an unobtrusive adapter in the JS?

Comment: It's up to you. I've always use this approach when custom client side validation was needed. Mark as answer is this helped you somehow:)